# NoSQL Data structure to select subset of fields with Firebase and query

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I’m creating a NoSQL database using Firebase, but as I’m a SQL thinker my mind needs some advices about Firebase queries and NoSQL Data Structure.

I am making some experiments for a Mobile App using also Ionic 2 (AngularJS 2), and my concerns are about the speed (user time) and the correct structure of my tables.

In the App I have a list of things that Users have Made and Users could be part of a Group, now following the de-normalization from the Firebase website I made this schema

```
Users : {
   Id : {
       Name: string
       Picture: base64 56x56 pixels (image)
       Addresses : {}
       Groups : {
           Worker: boolean 
           Student: boolean
       }
   }
}

Groups : {
  Worker : {
    Desc: string
    Members : {
      Userid: boolean
    }
  }
  Student : {
    Desc: string
    Members : {
      Userid: boolean
    }
  }
}

Made : {
  Id : {
    Name: string
    Thumb: base64 56x56 pixels (image)
    Desc: string
    User: userid
    Images:  base64 dimensions could vary
  }
}
```

What I have to do is to show a list of things that an user made, with few information like name and thumb image, by clicking on it opens the description with the other infos.

Now if I use the following snippet for getting the list, it returns me all the info but at the beginning I need just name and thumb (or something else)

```
return firebase.database().ref('/made/' + madeId)
.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  var username = snapshot.val().username;
  // ...
});
```

So, is there any way in firebase to do something like(?):

```
SELECT name, thumb FROM Table_Made
```

In order to get only the fields that I need for each query? Or

Is better to have another table with only the name and the image?

Is a good idea to have both thumb and the image? In order to speed up the json because the thumb is generally smaller than the image.

Looking at Firebase doc, it seems that images smaller than 10mb could be saved as base64 into the document and in case are bigger on the storage. What is your idea about that?

Comment: The fact that the Firebase Database has a 10MB limit on the size of a node, does not mean you should store images up to that size in the database. User-generated data for which you won't query the structure, can more efficiently be stored on/served from Firebase Storage.

Comment: Limit yourself to one question per post btw. It's hard to answer all of them in one go otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Firebase clients always retrieve complete nodes. There is no way to get just a subset of the properties of a node.

As usual: if you are having problems implementing your use-case on the data model, change the data model to fit your use-case. So in this case, that means that you could split off the name and thumbnail into a separate node.

```
MadeListinfo : {
  Id : {
    Name: string
    Thumb: base64 56x56 pixels (image)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is what I was thinking to split the data model in different sections and get only the data that I need.
Of course this means to be more careful about writing changes.